# What's DAX To extract employees ID's whose Shifts fall with in certain time slot

Tags: powerbi

I have table contains data col's of EmpID, Shift Start Time, Shift End Time & Resonable Notice Time in case of closing business before business hours. I'm trying to filter Employees whose ShiftStartTime is less than 2 hours of Resonable Notice Time of Closing so they get compensation as per the policy. My syntax does not fit to filter those employees. Please advise.

I also tried calculating time difference by using DATEDIFF as

Step 1

*Time Diff = DATEDIFF('Table1'[ShiftStartTime],'Table1'[Resonable Notice Time],MINUTE)*
Step 2
Trying to filter only those EmpID's who has less than 120 mins and >= 0 as they many not have had chance to clock in. but not getting right syntax
*EmpID's for Compensation = LOOKUPVALUE('Table1'[iEmpID],('Table1'[Time Diff]<120 &&'Table1'[Time Diff]>=0),BLANK())* Need help solving this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that 'Time_Diff' is a calculated column?

```
Time_Diff =
DATEDIFF ( 'Table1'[ShiftStartTime], 'Table1'[Resonable Notice Time], MINUTE )
```

Then I think you should use a table function (such as FILTER or summarize) instead of lookup value which returns a scalar value.
Please test this:

```
EmpID's for Compensation =
FILTER (
    ALL ( 'Table1'[iEmpID], 'Table1'[Time Diff] ),
    ( 'Table1'[Time Diff] < 120
        && 'Table1'[Time Diff] >= 0 )
)
```

Comment: Giving scalar value error - Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value

Comment: @SSFA Filter returns a table; If you want to see what it returns, you need to use 'create table' statement.